# Calculate percentage value of grouped value in geom_bar while showing count per grouped value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to show data of count & percentage in a stacked bar with ggplot2. Data ist here

https://github.com/oiramsch/CvsRWO/blob/master/colorList.csv

I tried this:

```
p <- colorList %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x=factor(age, levels = c("young","old")),fill=factor(answer_correct, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("False","Correct"))))
```

**and then**

```
p + geom_bar(stat="count", position="stack")+facet_grid(~condition)+labs(title="Colors",subtitle = "per setsize grouped by age", x="", y="Count answer correct", fill="Answer correct")+geom_text(aes(label = paste(..count..,"\n",scales::percent(..count../1298,0.01))),position=position_stack(0.5),stat="count")
```

as a result I receive:

[image: Bar Chart]

The problem is that I use a fixed value of 1298 as the total value to calculate the percentage share ( which is unfortunately not true for all columns). So I'm looking for an internal variable of ggplot which I could use to access the sum per column or even better the percentage of the false/correct values per set size. But I was not able to figure out how to do this. Of cause I could summarise the data in advance but I thought there must be a solution inside of ggplot...If there is someone, who has an idea how I can fix my code I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this approach summarising values which can be an option for you:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
colorList <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oiramsch/CvsRWO/master/colorList.csv',stringsAsFactors = F)
#Aggregate
colorList %>% mutate(age=factor(age, levels = c("young","old")),
             answer_correct=factor(answer_correct, levels = c(0,1))) %>%
  group_by(age,condition,answer_correct) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(age,condition) %>% 
  mutate(Total=sum(N),Percent=N/Total,
         Lab=paste0(N,' (',paste0(round(100*Percent,0),'%'),')')) -> Sums
#Plot
ggplot(Sums,aes(x=age,y=N,fill=answer_correct))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = position_stack())+
  facet_wrap(.~condition,scales = 'free')+
  geom_text(aes(label=Lab),position = position_stack(vjust = .5),size=3)+
  geom_text(aes(y=Total,label=Total),vjust=-0.25,size=3)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thx duck, may be you're right and aggregating the data before plotting it, is easier than looking for an internal solution in ggplot. that's pragmatic and fast. I thought ggplot could do it itself but may be I'm wrong. Thank you for your code.

Comment: @Oiramsch Yeah it is more optimal coding your data so that you obtain the perfect input for your plot as you can see. I hope this was useful for you and if you believe this was a helpful answer you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer. It is up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `(..count..)/sum(..count..)`?

```
p + 
  geom_bar(stat="count", position="stack")+
  facet_grid(~condition)+
  labs(title="Colors",subtitle = "per setsize grouped by age", x="", y="Count answer correct", fill="Answer correct")+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(..count..,"\n",
                              scales::percent(..count../sum(..count..), 0.01))),
            position=position_stack(0.5),stat="count")
```

Comment: Thx Liman, I tried it. But `sum(..count..)` is giving back the total of all correct answers, so about 10400. I'm looking for the total of correct/false answers per column. I thought there is an internal variable ..??.. that sums up per bar.